# How to install a package to Macaulay 2 in Linux?

Tags: terminal, software-installation, package-management, command, github

Could anyone please help me with exactly how to install the Bertini package to [Macaulay 2](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/) by typing lines of commands in a terminal of Linux?

Or what command should I type in a terminal of CentOS to, perhaps directly, install the pacakge from  https://github.com/diegcif/SumsOfSquares.m2 ?

Many thanks.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time trying to install it but could not install it by myself.

Comment: Have you used Google to go to the website and follow the instructions?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes, I googled, but many people said it is hard to follow, not only in installing a package but also in installing the software.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you having issues? Depending on the version of CentOS, you'll either use `yum` to install it or compile it from source?

Answer (score 0):

To install a package for yourself only (the `$` at the beginning of a line represents a Linux terminal prompt):

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.Macaulay2/code
$ cd $HOME/.Macaulay2/code
$ wget https://github.com/diegcif/SumsOfSquares.m2
$ cd 
$ M2
[...version number and a list of loaded Macaulay2 packages...]

i1: installPackage SumsOfSquares
```